# Can I set a minimum positive and a minimum negative axis value in Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have created a `jsfiddle` which includes 3 scenarios, 
http://jsfiddle.net/wf_4/7mK9X/

The first, all negative bars, the second all positive bars and the third is a mix of both positive and negative.

What I don't like is that when all values are either positive or negative that the bars (especially when all negative) start at the end of the chart.

What I would like to do is to be able to set a `min: -10` AND `min: 10` so that regardless of how the data turns out either all pos, all neg or mixed, that there will be at least some space on either side of the bars.

[image: Image to show the current and desired behaviour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use load callback, to set new extremes: http://jsfiddle.net/7mK9X/2/

```
var setEx = function(){
     var chart = this,
         ex = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();


    if(ex.min == 0) {
         chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(-10, ex.max);   
    } else if(ex.max == 0 ) {
         chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(ex.min, 10); 
    }

}

$('#container1').highcharts({
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: setEx
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
    },
    series: [{
        data: [-29.9, -71.5, -106.4],
        type: 'bar',
        name: 'All Negative'
    }]
});
```

Comment: That is exactly the look that I am going for. Is it possible to use something like `ready` instead of `load` so that you do not get the animation when adding the extremes?

Comment: You can disable animation for setExtremes(), but this will disable animations at all: http://jsfiddle.net/7mK9X/3/ Another solution is to call setExtremes() in `setTimeout( function () { ... }, 1000)`, where 1000 is default value for animations. If none of above will work for you, then always you can create tickPositioner, and calculate axis ticks the way you need.

Comment: adding the `, true, false` when calling `.setExtremes` as detailed in your fiddle did the trick. Perfect solution, thank you.